# Преобразовать строки таблицы БД в колонки

Tags: sql

Помогите из исходной таблицы, где обозначения расположены в одной колонке,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с помощью SQL получить следующую таблицу, где эти же обозначения распределены по двум колонкам, но в одной строке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Из вопрос не ясно какая субд, в общем смотрите в сторону PIVOT

Comment: Запрос должен отработать в любой СУБД.

Comment: *Запрос должен отработать в любой СУБД.* Да проще Луну с неба достать.

Comment: это специфический синтаксис поддерживается только в некоторых СУБД и имеет отличия в реализации. В ANSI SQL PIVOT/UNPIVOT не входит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если значений для reference не более двух, то для любой СУБД:

```
select reference, min(destination) destination1,
nullif(max(destination),min(destination)) destination2 
from tbl
group by reference;
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! Правда в моей СУБД нет nullif, поэтому запрос переделал:SELECT Reference, MIN(Designation) AS Designation1,
CASE 
    WHEN MAX(Designation) <> MIN(Designation)
    THEN MAX(Designation)
    ELSE NULL
    END AS Designation2
FROM
    Tbl
GROUP BY Reference;